# Select Date query from MS-Access DATETIME column

Tags: delphi

I am currently working on "Delphi XE4" with "MS Access" Database.Tools I am using is ADOCommand, ADOQuery, ADOConnection,ADOTable and Datasource

In my user interfaced project, User is selecting range of Dates and using that date I am selecting a records from database.

But problem is,in my database column is in DATETIME Format (5/21/2015 02:30:00 PM) and user is selecting only a DATE eg., 5/21/2015.

Now how can I select records from database using DATE only.

Please Note that I already tried to fire Select query for example,

```
ADOQuery.SQL.ADD('SELECT * From Tablename') ;
ADOQuery.SQL.ADD('WHERE Cast(DateTimeField As DATE) = #5/21/2015# ');
```

and this also

```
ADOQuery.SQL.ADD('SELECT * From Tablename') ;
ADOQuery.SQL.ADD('WHERE Convert(DATE,DateTimeField, 101) = #5/21/2015# ');
```

but this give to error "Undefined Function 'Cast/Convert' in expression"

Is there any other way to do this??

Can anybody suggest me how can I fetch records by fetching Date from "DATETIME fields" using select query?

Answer (score 1):

ANd welcome to SO.

You should not try to parse the date you self you should use a parameterized query instead.

So

```
ADOQuery.SQL.ADD('SELECT * From Tablename') ;
ADOQuery.SQL.ADD('WHERE Convert(DATE,DateTimeField, 101) = #5/21/2015# ');
```

Should be changed to

```
ADOQuery.SQL.ADD('SELECT * From Tablename') ;
ADOQuery.SQL.ADD('WHERE DATE = :DateValue');
```

Then when you call your Query do as following:

```
  ADOQuery1.Close;
  ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('DateValue').Value := Now;
  ADOQuery1.Open;
```

The the SQL engine does the trick for it. Try it and if you can't make it work I'll make a complete example for you

Answer (score 0):

The way I use dates in MSAccess with Delphi is

```
ADOQuery.SQL.ADD('SELECT * From Tablename') ;
ADOQuery.SQL.ADD('WHERE DateTimeField = Format(''21/05/2015'', ''dd/mm/yyyy'') ');
```

I hope it helps!